# How to use urllib.urlencode? What are the the type of those two variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

if I do like :

```
postData = urllib.urlencode({
    'zip':'98105',
    'zipCode':'98115'
})
```

For 'zip', What is the type of the 'first position variable'. Is it a HTML id, or HTML class, or what? For '98105', is this the value I was trying to change?

Comment: If you're posting data, `zip` is a `POST` variable. You can read it in PHP. `$_POST["zip"]` would be the syntax if I recall correctly, and that would return `"98105"`.

Comment: What do you mean by " first positional variable"? There is only one positional argument here, and it is a dict. And urlencode has nothing to do with HTML at all.

Answer (score 2):

urlencode creates "websafe" urls for you.

```
postData = urllib.urlencode({
    'zip':'98105',
    'zipCode':'98115'
})
```

in this case postData equals `'zipCode=98115&zip=98105'`

> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a
>   “percent-encoded” string, suitable to pass to urlopen() above as the
>   optional data argument. This is useful to pass a dictionary of form
>   fields to a POST request. The resulting string is a series of
>   key=value pairs separated by '&' characters, where both key and value
>   are quoted using quote_plus() above. When a sequence of two-element
>   tuples is used as the query argument, the first element of each tuple
>   is a key and the second is a value. The value element in itself can be
>   a sequence and in that case, if the optional parameter doseq is
>   evaluates to True, individual key=value pairs separated by '&' are
>   generated for each element of the value sequence for the key. The
>   order of parameters in the encoded string will match the order of
>   parameter tuples in the sequence. The urlparse module provides the
>   functions parse_qs() and parse_qsl() which are used to parse query
>   strings into Python data structures.

source:
[Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#utility-functions)

Answer (score -2):

If you're posting data, `zip` is a `POST` variable. You can read it in PHP for example. `$_POST["zip"]` would be the variable it's stored in, and that would contain `"98105"`.

Put simply, if you had a PHP page which contained:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["zip"];
?>
```

It would display:

```
98105
```

Comment: The top voted answer doesn't explain the data in transit and that seemed to be what OP was asking. I tried to cover that. Any suggestions for improvement?